# foreach loop executing multiple times

Tags: php, cakephp, foreach

I have an array and based on the id I have to insert in different table. But the problem is that array executing multiple times.Suppose I have this id 1 for 3 times, id 2 for 2 times. total data inserting 9 times for id 1 and 4 times for id 2. What am I missing. My code

```
if (!empty($this->request->data['other_source_options'])) {
    foreach ($this->request->data['other_source_options'] as $value) {
      if ($value == 1) {
           $this->__function_name_1(1);
         }
      if ($value == 2) {
           $this->__function_name_2(2);
          }
      if ($value == 3) {
          $this->__function_name_3(3);
          }
      if ($value == 4) {
          $this->__function_name_4(4);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the array `$this->request->data['other_source_options']` gotta see what it contains before coming up with a solution

Comment: array(
 (int) 0 => '1',
 (int) 1 => '1',
 (int) 2 => '1',
 (int) 3 => '2',
 (int) 4 => '2'
)

Comment: id 1 is coming 3 times, so are we gonna call the function 3 times? And function 2 twice?

Comment: yes. id 1 for 3 times and 2 for twice

Comment: There's not enough info in order to be able to come to any conclusions. Nobody knows where that code lives, how it is being invoked, what the functions do, etc. Please always make sure that your examples do contain enough information for others to reproduce the problem! Also do some debugging first and show the results, like check whether that code snippet is being executed more than once, show the stacktrace of the invocation, show the data that you're working with (post it in your question, not in a comment), etc...

Comment: thanks @ndm I'll keep that on mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_unique function (Refer from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_unique.asp)).
You can use below code:

```
 <?php
  if (!empty($this->request->data['other_source_options'])) {
  $arrUnique = array_unique($this->request->data['other_source_options']);

foreach ($arrUnique as $value) {
  if ($value == 1) {
       $this->__function_name_1(1);
     }
  if ($value == 2) {
       $this->__function_name_2(2);
      }
  if ($value == 3) {
      $this->__function_name_3(3);
      }
  if ($value == 4) {
      $this->__function_name_4(4);
    }
}
 }
   ?>
```

Comment: thanks AddWeb. But I have solved it in a different way. Removed the other_souce_options array entirely.